# How to check iframe is empty?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I have 2 different codes. 1 is null and the other is not null.

My code with null: (== empty)

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <iframe style="width:868px; height:550px;" id="FileReload" src="/Account/GetPDF?NUM=101">
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>
            </body>
        </html>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

My code not null: (!= empty)

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <iframe style="width:868px; height:550px;" id="FileReload" src="/Account/GetPDF?NUM=101">
        <html>
            <body style="background-color: rgb(38,38,38); height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin: 0">
            <embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" id="plugin" src="http://localhost:49943/Account/GetPDF?NUM=101" type="application/pdf" internalinstanceid="74" title="">
            </body>
        </html>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

My Controler:

```
public ActionResult GetPDF(int NUM)
{
    //.Select Database
    //.
    //.
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        //Here passes null or not null.
        PDF = ((byte[])reader["File"]);
        return new FileContentResult(PDF, "application/pdf");
    }
}
```

**When null, iframe is white.
When not null, it works fine. (I want to hide iframe when layout is white.)**

It looks like this: (iframe white)

[image]

When is null, display white iframe width and height.(if == null -> hide iframe)

How to check if it is null using javascript?

Comment: What do you consider `null` to mean?

Comment: None of those iFrames are empty, so I guess you have to be more specific?

Comment: @ScottMarcus When is null (empty), do not show white iframes.

Comment: @adeneo Okay, I'll specify more.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda No, not what to do when it's null. What do you define null as being (i.e. completely empty or having no element content)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

```
$(function() {
  $('#FileReload').load(function() {            
    if ($.trim($(this).contents().find("body").find('embed').length) == 0) {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Although it uses jQuery, don't worry